# Duplicate rows when getting list of latest revisions of a content type

Tags: views, 8

I want to create a list of latest revisions of a content type, in a specific moderation state to use in a custom dashboard.

It needs to have the following fields listed in a table form.

- Content Title
- Language
- Node ID
- Content Type

Here is what I tried
1. Created a view with Content Revisions
2. Filter with Latest revisions
(Everything works fine upto here)
3. Since I want to include content type, its not available in revisions, I added a **Content** revision.
(There appears a lot of duplicated rows)

How to tackle this? I tried adding aggregation with minimal success.